# Directory extraction task in workflow extracts unexpected items（Digdag workflow）

Tags: etl, workflow

I have a question about Digdag workflows.
In a .dig file, I have the following configuration:

```
_export:
  plugin:
    repositories:
      - https://jitpack.io/
    dependencies:
      - com.github.takemikami:digdag-plugin-shresult:0.0.3

+find_dirs:
  sh_result>: |
    find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | grep -v "^.$" | grep -E '^\[' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
  destination_variable: dirs
  stdout_format: text

+call_dig:
  for_each>:
    dir: "${dirs.split(',')}"
  _parallel: true
  _do:
    +loop_dig:
      call>: ${dir}/unload.dig
```

In the ‘+find_dirs’ task, I’m attempting to extract directory names that start with ‘[’ and store them in the ‘dirs’ variable. However, during Digdag execution, there are instances where items other than directory names starting with ‘[’ are being stored in ‘dirs’.
Is this potentially a bug in Digdga or plugin? I would appreciate your confirmation.
Here are the ‘dirs’ values that I want to extract and the ‘dirs’ values that were mistakenly extracted in this operation:

Desired ‘dirs’:
`dirs: [foo1]bar1,[foo2]bar2,[foo3]bar3,[foo4]bar4`

‘Dirs’ extracted in the current operation (Example 1: Code from the executed workflow’s .dig file is being extracted):

```
dirs: >+ 
2023-09-14 21:45:48 +0000 [INFO] (1913@[0:test_wf]+test_coordinator+call_dig^sub^sub+find_dirs) io.digdag.core.agent.OperatorManager: sh_result>: find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | grep -v "^.$" | grep -E '^\[' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

‘Dirs’ extracted in the current operation (Example 2: Logs from other projects executed at the same time are being extracted):

```
dirs: >- 
2023-09-07 09:15:02 +0000 [INFO] (5117@[0:cost_alert]+cost_change+scripts+notice) io.digdag.core.agent.OperatorManager: sh>: cd cost_alert python3 [main.py](http://main.py/) -t increase [foo1]bar1,[foo2]bar2,[foo3]bar3,[foo4]bar4
```

[Problem Information]
digdag: 0.10.4
macOS: 12.6